# function caller invalid element

Tags: javascript, function, function-call

If I have :

```
<div id="mydiv" onmouseover="myfunc()">
  <div id="mydiv1"></div>
  <div id="mydiv2"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function myfunc() {
    var evt = window.event || arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0];
    var em = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    return em.id;
  }
</script>
```

The function is called by `mydiv` onmouseover, but if mouse cursor is over `mydiv1` function returns `mydiv1`.

**How to make it always to show `mydiv`?**

*P.S : I know that I can use something like `myfunc(this)`, but I would like to find caller from inside my function.*

Comment: `this` will give you the caller. Perhaps what you need is not clear. You need to elaborate your question.

Comment: It won't because `myfunc` gets executed in the context of the global object (`window`). He needs to attach the handler via JS as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would prefer to use jQuery to hook up the event:

```
$('#mydiv').on('mouseover',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // ...
});
```

If this should be applied to several elements, then use a class selector instead:

```
$('.hoverable').on('mouseover',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // ...
});
```

To also handle future content, attach the event handler to a common ancestor, and select the hoverable elements in the second parameter to `on`:

```
$('body').on('mouseover','.hoverable',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // ...
});
```

[See it in action with future content here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/XVbyf/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the event handler via JavaScript. You can then access the element it is directly bound to as `this` inside it.

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydiv1"></div>
  <div id="mydiv2"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function myFunc() {
    return this.id;
  }

  var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  mydiv.onmouseover = myFunc;
</script>
```

Comment: I have about 100 different div's to call my function, and I think,  writing 200 lines of javascript will not be the best option

Comment: Then loop through them. Polluting the markup with JS code is a bad practice.

Comment: By "different" I mean : one may have id, another may not have id; one may be "div" element one "a" or "span".. basically the function is a custom tooltip. If is not possible with caller, I think I will use mufunc(this)

Comment: Then maybe a `class="tooltip"`?

Comment: Maybe, but what if new content will be added with Ajax?

Comment: Then add the class `tooltip` to the new content as well as needed.

Comment: @supr Javascript won't match them, right? because javascript will be executed, for example on page load, but new elements may be added after 5, 10 minutes

Comment: @supr using intervals to loop 100-200 elements each some minutes, I think, wont' help more.

Comment: You can have a function that attaches the listeners to a part of the DOM tree (you would pass the root element of the subtree to the function). You would call it with the body element on page load and then, when new content is fetched via XHR, you would pass the root element of the new content to that function.

Comment: Thanks it helps, I will think about your answer

Comment: @John, it depends on how you use javascript to hook it up. You can do as Jan says and apply it explicitly every time new content is added. An alternative if you use jQuery is so called delegated events. I'll update my answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

You can  do this using Jquery easily.

```
$('#mydiv').hover(function(){
alert(this.id);
```

});​​​​​​

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/shahvj27/6zE96/